# Internal and orthogonal direct sum isomorphic in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $E$ and $F$ be two closed subspaces of $H$ such that $H = E \oplus F$ as an internal direct sum. Can we conclude that $H$ is isomorphic to $E \times F$, where $E \times F$ is considered as a Hilbert space with the inner product $$\langle (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \rangle = \langle x_1, y_1 \rangle_H + \langle x_2, y_2 \rangle_H $$ via the map $i:x \mapsto (e_x, f_x)$, where $x = e_x + f_x$ is the decomposition in the internal direct sum?

If $F = E^\perp$, then this question is trivial.

However, we know that $F$ need not be equal to $E^\perp$ ([Does orthogonal decomposition characterize direct sums in Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398764/does-orthogonal-decomposition-characterize-direct-sums-in-hilbert-space)). In this case, are we able to conclude they are isomorphic as Hilbert spaces via the canonical map? I do not know how to approach this.

I cannot conclude that $i$ is bounded directly, since $$||i(x)|| = \sqrt{||e_x||^2 + ||f_x||^2}, $$ which is not equal to $||e_x + f_x|| = x$, and it is always larger than this (by the triangle inequality).

Is it important that $H$ is a Hilbert space? We can ask the same question if $H$ is a Banach space. Will the answer change?

Comment: This is true if and only if $E$ and $F$ are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a consequence of the closed graph Theorem, hence a non-trivial fact, that, whenever a Banach space $X$ is the (algebraic) direct sum of two closed subspaces $E$ and $F$, then the natural projections $\pi_E$ and $\pi_F$ are continuous.  Therefore, for every $x$ in $E$, the new norm
$$
   |||x||| = \|\pi_E(x)\| + \|\pi_F(x)\|
   $$
is equivalent to the original norm on $X$, and hence $X$ is isomorphic and homeomorphic to $E\times F$ via the map described by the OP.

Comment: Equivalent norms need not be isometric right? I don't think that the norm $||| \cdot |||$ comes from an inner product to being with, so they won't be isometric as Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Equivalent norms need not be equal!  It is enough that $A\|x\|\leq |||x|||\leq B\|x\|$, for all $x$.  And yes, the norm
need not come from an inner product, but if would would like it to be just define it as  $|||x||| = (\|\pi_E(x)\|^2 +
\|\pi_F(x)\|^2)^{1/2}$ and everythig else will be just the same.